# Pareto distribution (integration)

Tags: integration, statistics, actuarial-science, integration-by-parts

The random variable $X$ follows a Pareto distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\lambda$.
I need to show the below:
[image]

I have come across the following answer, but couldn't understand step 2.
I have tried integration by parts with no success.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your approach to integration by parts is something like $\displaystyle \int_b^c u \, dv=\bigg[uv\bigg]_b^c-\int_b^c v \, du$

then try $u=x$ and $dv=\dfrac{\alpha \lambda^\alpha}{(\lambda+x)^{\alpha+1}}\, dx$, so $du = dx$ and $v=-\dfrac{ \lambda^\alpha}{(\lambda+x)^{\alpha}}$

Comment: Thank you!
When I tried it the first time I miscalculated it. Got it now.